# how to change number of columns in django template with screen size

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, python-2.7, django-templates

when the page is viewed with 768*1280 (smartphone) resolution it looks like
[image: page columns on small screen]

django template for the web page is

```
<div class="row">
{% for discount in object_list %}
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <!--<img src="{{static_url}}images/vendor/{{ discount.product_vendor__vendor_logo }}" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">-->
            <img src="{% static "images/vendor/" %}{{ discount.product_vendor__vendor_logo }}" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <img src="{% static "images/products/" %}{{ discount.product_vendor__vendor_alias }}/full/{{ discount.product_image }}" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            {{ discount.product_name }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <h5>{{ discount.product_price }}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <strike>
            <h5>{{ discount.product_price_old }}</h5>
            </strike>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
        </div>
                <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <h5>{{ discount.product_vendor__vendor_odeliver }}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <h5>{{ discount.diff }}</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    <!-- if last column in row -->
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"4" and not forloop.last %}
    </div><div class="row">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to change in **divisibleby:"4"** the number 4 with respect to the size of the screen. example, divisibleby:"1" for mobile screens and divisibleby:"3" for tablets and divisibleby:"4" for desktops. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no particular reason that each product gets separated into rows. This makes your templating work way harder. I am not even sure that you need to use `divisibleby`. I would recommend something like:

```
{% for discount in object_list %}
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <!--<img src="{{static_url}}images/vendor/{{ discount.product_vendor__vendor_logo }}" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">-->
        <img src="{% static "images/vendor/" %}{{ discount.product_vendor__vendor_logo }}"
             class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
        <img src="
                {% static "images/products/" %}{{ discount.product_vendor__vendor_alias }}/full/{{ discount.product_image }}"
             class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
        {{ discount.product_name }}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <h5>{{ discount.product_price }}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <strike>
                    <h5>{{ discount.product_price_old }}</h5>
                </strike>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <h5>{{ discount.product_vendor__vendor_odeliver }}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <h5>{{ discount.diff }}</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

If for some reason (eg. variable heights of items) you indeed need to use `divisibleby`, then add a `<div class="clearfix"></div>` or take care of your heights.